Python library to parse a wide range of possibly incomplete datestrings into the date ranges they represent
I'm looking for a library that helps me parse the date ranges represented by a wide variety of date strings.
For example, 2023Q1 should be parsed as daterange(start=date(2023,01,01),end=date(2023,04,01)) (end-exclusive), whereas 2023-02-03 should be daterange(start=date(2023,02,03),end=date(2023,02,04)) etc.
Previously, I was using pandas' internal function parsing.parse_datetime_string_with_reso but using non-public APIs like this is a bad idea, I'd like something more stable.
To my surprise, I haven't been able to find a library that does this job without requiring some hacks. Has anyone else encountered and maybe solved this issue?

I've found something promising, Python-EDTF: https://github.com/ixc/python-edtf
It has a parser which creates a rich internal representation that can then queried in various ways, e.g. lower_strict/upper_strict, and lower_fuzzy/upper_fuzzy. It handles a lot of things that go beyond what I think I need, e.g. handling ambiguous months when the date is known.
Overall, a lot of thought seems to have gone into this library.
